# IE 11 Javascript regex replace incorrectly replaces meta characters

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

When using regex replace function on a string containing some combination of regex meta characters, the characters that are replaced in the string are replaced incorrectly.

I have been using the following expression:

`string.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")`

This works in Chrome at least and works fine in JSFiddle for example, however in IE 11 (and probably most versions of IE), this incorrectly replaces the character with something incorrect, for example:

```
var string = "test (fake)";
string = string.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
```

results in:

`test \\(fake\\)` instead of `test \(fake\)`

I originally assumed that I could just remove one of the slashes in the second argument for `replace()`, however that results in:

`test (fake)`

Basically, I seem to be unable to escape these characters because I don't know how to specify that I want it to be replaced with literally `\(` instead of `(` or `\\(`.

Has anyone run into this before and have a solution, any idea on how I can get around this or some alternate method of escaping these characters? Changing browser is unfortunately not an option.

Here's a JSFiddle for reference to show it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/k42uygm8/5/

Comment: Try https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#escapeRegExp

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k42uygm8/5/ does not open in my IE11:( Actually, I believe what you see is not what you get: that is probably the "console view", that shows a string literal and not a literal string.

Comment: Actually, I get a single backslash using your jsfiddler sample here in a stack snipped viewed in IE11.

Comment: I noticed it first when debugging; my regex pattern was wrong and wasn't matching correctly. Interesting that two people opened it in IE 11, one didn't even open and one worked. That lodash function seems like it will suffer from the same problem I ran into since it's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to solve this in the following fashion:

`string = string.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "[$&]");`

Since I want to match the character anyway, I can just surround it with square brackets instead of trying to escape it.

I guess this is just a bug with the Javascript engine in my specific version of IE, nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

As a replacement string you specified `\\$&`.

Theoretically it is OK, but apparently some verions of JavaScript regex
use `$0` as a reference to the whole match.

I tested your regex and replacement string under regex101.com (JavaScript regex flavour)
and found out that `$0` version works there.

So try to change the replacement string to `\\$0`.

**Another remark:**

Within char classes (between `[` and `]`) you don't need to escape:

- the **leading** or **trailing** minus,
- **opening** square bracket (`[`),
- braces and parentheses (`{}()`),
- quantifiers (`*+?`),
- a dot,
- `^` and `$` anchors,
- vertical bar.

So you can shorten your regex to `[-[\]\/{}()*+?.\\^$|]`.

### Edit

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch
concerning `$&` and notice the fragment: *This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried what you suggested, however I encountered the same issue in that the character that is being replaced, is replaced with `\\(` substituting any character for the '(';